# Django model deconstruct() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Can someone give a solid example of the deconstruct() mentioned in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing. 
I read the doc, and can't really understand with an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related Django Ticket - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22951
and here is an example:

```
class Klass:
    def __init__(self, x, y, sep=','):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sep = sep

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sep.join((str(self.x), str(self.y)))

    def deconstruct(self):
        return 'python.path.to.your.Klass', [self.x, self.y], \
               {'sep': self.sep}
```

And of course don't forget that the order of the returned list of `args` should be the same the original order (from the `__init__` method) of positional arguments.

Comment: I had the same question, but this answer just raises more questions. Your __init__ takes four arguments, your deconstruct returns three.